# How to generate 5% out of order text files

Tags: java, sorting, random, integer

My class and I are working on a programming assignment for Java that tests running times for different sorting algorithms.  We generate text files that store different amounts of randomly generated integers.  The sizes are: 100, 1000, 10 000, 100 000, 1 000 000.  I am able to run the sorting algorithms correctly on these files but have no idea how to do the next step.

We need to create or modify these text files so only 5% of the random ints are out of place.  I cannot just move the last 5% because it has to be evenly distributed.  Also, he said when 'disordering' these files, that an integer that has been moved out of place should not be moved again to prevent the occurrence of it being moved back where it was.  Anyone have any ideas how I would do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int n = 100;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  numbers.add(i);
}
//The array is now 1, 2, 3, ..., 99, 100. Critically, it is sorted.

List<Integer> disordered = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
    // 5% chance of taking a number from numbers and adding it to disordered
    numbers.remove(i);
    disordered.add(i);
  }
}

while (!disordered.isEmpty()) {
  int x = disordered.remove(0); // Pick a number from disordered
  int position = Math.random()*numbers.size(); // Generate a random number in the domain of numbers
  numbers.add(position, x);
}
```

I hope this is what you mean by "5% out of order." Note that numbers might show up where they originally were, but no number will be moved twice.

Comment: My hero.  Didn't know about using Math.random() like that.  Thanks a ton.